# Blender not loading properly

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, windows

I have installed Blender 2.76b in my computer. But when I open blender, it does not load fully and only icons are visible. This is how it looks:
[image]

I have installed Unity 5 in my system and that is working fine. 
Can anyone give a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is commonly because you installed Blender as one user (administrator) and are running it as a different user.

From http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?196976-My-Blender-2-5-Interface-is-Mostly-Empty

> Happens when you run Blender as a different user as who installed it (Windows).
>   Reason: The blender folder in User-Folder / Appdata /Roaming is required but only there for the user who installed it
>   Workaround: Always run Blender as the primary user (Run as Administrator) or: Copy the Blender Foundation folder from Appdata/Roaming of the primary user to your account's folder.

So, Blender doesn't have access to some of the folders it needs because they are on another user's account. This could also apply to some Python scripts. If Python was installed by another user, you might not have access to it on your account.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not sure this is the case. No text is rendering, which may be an OpenGL driver error.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the answer. But I ran Blender as administrator, but the problem still persists. Where should I copy the Blender Foundation folder from  User-Folder / Appdata /Roaming/ to?

Comment: @ideasman42: How can the problem of OpenGL driver solved?

Comment: @user24533 You should copy it to the same location in your folder. So if your user is named "Fred" and your admin account is named "admin" then you'd copy it from `C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming` to `C:/Users/Fred/AppDataRoaming`**BUT** if your problem is actually the same as the other questions linked above, then copying those files won't help.